# Could not able to create an executable(.exe) from Azure Devops pipelines release

Tags: azure-devops, executable, installshield, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

I am working for a WPF application, and recently I have migrated TFS to Azure DevOps and I am successfully able to create build artifacts as well, unfortunately, I could not create executable from the artifacts as Azure DevOps does not support InstallShield Package creation with it, now I decided to move the build artifacts to my local build server,again my company law doesn't allow to access my server from outside network, what should do to create executable.

Comment: not sure where is the question. you can do anything you want with your local build server

Answer (score 0):

The Build Agent needs to be able to connect to Azure DevOps. It's enough for it to be able to make an outgoing connection over https (443). The agent can be configured to connect through a web proxy server.

What alternatives do you have:

- Use the hosted agent and install InstallShield as part of the build process. This will be slow, but it is doable. You'll need to execute this step as part of every build that tries to create the InstallShield package and requires you to do a head-less installation of InstallShield (given that they are the kings of Installers, I suppose this is doable).
- Use a private agent in Azure. You can spin up any IaaS server on Azure, install Visual Studio, InstallShield and the Azure DevOps Agent on it and use it as a build server. [There is a set of standard images file available which you can use as a basis](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/tree/master/images/win).